# Rust thread 'main' has overflowed its stack

Tags: rust

I'm trying to re-implement this C code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 100000
#define COLS 10000

int twodarray[ROWS][COLS];

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            twodarray[i][j] = rand();
        }
    }

    int64 sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            sum += twodarray[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

So, after a lot of trial and error I've come up with Rust code that at least compiles

```
extern crate rand;

const ROWS: usize = 100000;
const COLS: usize = 10000;

fn main() {
    let mut twodarray: [[u128; COLS]; ROWS] = [[0; COLS]; ROWS];

    for i in 0..ROWS {
        for j in 0..COLS {
            twodarray[i][j] = rand::random::<u8>() as u128;
        }
    }

    let mut sum: u128 = 0;
    for k in 0..ROWS {
        for j in 0..COLS {
            sum += twodarray[k][j] as u128;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

But when I compile and execute it, I get the following error message: `thread 'main' has overflowed its stack`. To be honest, I have absolutelly no idea why this is happening. I'm currently learning rust, but there is not a lot of information on 2d arrays online... I DO NOT WANT TO USE VECTOR. This exercise is specifically aimed on arrays.

EDIT:
After reading the accepted answear, I've come up with Rust code that outputs expected results:

```
extern crate rand;

const ROWS: usize = 100000;
const COLS: usize = 10000;

fn main() {
    // let mut twodarray: Box<[[u8; COLS]; ROWS]> = Box::new([[0; COLS]; ROWS]);
    // for i in 0..ROWS {
    //     for j in 0..COLS {
    //         twodarray[i][j] = rand::random::<u8>();
    //     }
    // }

    // let mut sum: u32 = 0;
    // for k in 0..ROWS {
    //     for l in 0..COLS {
    //         sum += twodarray[k][l] as u32;
    //     }
    // }

    let mut twodarray: Box<[[u8; ROWS]; COLS]> = Box::new([[0; ROWS]; COLS]);
    for i in 0..COLS {
        for j in 0..ROWS {
            twodarray[i][j] = rand::random::<u8>();
        }
    }

    let mut sum: u32 = 0;
    for k in 0..COLS {
        for l in 0..ROWS {
            sum += twodarray[k][l] as u32;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe `twodarray` is too big for memory?

Comment: Hmmm, based on my calculation it should be around 4GB, but I have more than 4GB of free memory available (around 10GB rn)

Comment: The array has a billion elements, and each is 16 bytes, so it would be (at least) 16GB, no?

Comment: Really? How come the C code runs just fine than?

Comment: In the C code, the array is global.  I think that's the difference.  Globals go on the heap, not the stack, as I recall.

Comment: Oh, ok, is there a way to alocate this array on heap in Rust?

Comment: Globals in C are stored in static memory, which is effectively the same place that the *code* for your program is stored; i.e., it's loaded when the program is first loaded. Heap memory is used for dynamic allocation through `malloc` or (in C++) `new`.

Comment: Hm, so, for example if I were to use the `time` command to time the programs. I should expect the C program to take longer, because it takes longer to start the program as the 4gb of memory are loaded when the program loads? But then be faster when using this memory?

Comment: @TDiblik I don't think the C program will be any slower; C is smart enough not to "load" zero-initialized memory from the actual executable, it just reserves it at run-time in the section of the memory marked for globals.

Comment: Funnily enough, code truly equivalent to the provided C currently cannot be written (at least in the obvious way) because the compiler [spends all available memory](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93215).

Comment: Lol, it (compiler spent all available memory) happened to me while playing around with the source (had to restart my pc), but I thought that it was just some kind of random weird non-reproduceable bug :D. For the C program being slower, I had some weird experience, because when I've compiled the Rust program with opt-lever 3 and --release (cargo), I've got around 3.7 seconds real time (using `time` command), but when I compiled the C program, I've always achieved around 9-10 seconds real time (without compiler optimalization flags). Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @TDiblik Yes, you should specify `-O2` or equivalent to the C compiler, otherwise the comparison is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This two-dimensional array is huge. Rust tries to allocate it on the stack (that's the way arrays in Rust work).

You explicitly wrote you didn't want to use vectors, but in reality vectors are allocated on the heap, so you wouldn't have such a problem with them. It's good to keep that in mind.

If you insist on using arrays, maybe put them in a `Box`, so that they go to the heap?

That's not a Rust-specific problem. Stacks are generally a lot more limited, compared to the heap, usually up to a few megabytes. In some other languages, such as Java, arrays are allocated on the heap, but that doesn't mean there is no similar stack size limit there as well.